# How to style dropdown flex-block so it wouldn't push content under him, but overlap it without position?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

I have this code. 
When i click on second menu bar - flex dropdownmenu goes down. 
But it pushes "header-flex" and other content under him down.
How can i make dropdown menu so it would overlap and not push blocks away?
I've tried position: relative-absolute, but it seems to break flex-container.
Is there a way to do this withoud position: relative/absolute?
Or maybe a way to "fix" flex and not let it break with all adaptive features?

Thanks

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}

.dropdown-menu-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block-header {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #595959;
    background-color: #dedede;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
     padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block-element a {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #167491;
}

.hide {
    display: none; 
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.hide:checked + label + div {
    display: flex; 
}


@media (max-width: 444px) {
 .hide, .hide + label ~ div {
    display: none; 
}

.hide:checked + label + div {
    display: block; 
}

.hide + label:before {
    background-color: #2CB1D9;
    color: black;
    content: "\002B";
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 3px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
  
.hide:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2212";
}
  
  .dropdown-menu {
    gap: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu-column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu-column-block-header {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu-column-block {
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu-column-block-element a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  }
  
  .header-flex {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1240px;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;  
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .article-header {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.article-header-price {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px; 
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar-button {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(//pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/feedBackButton.png);
    height: 40px;
    width: 187px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #863e39;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar-button:hover {
    background-color: #1fa6ce;
    background-image: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  max-width: 1240px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('https://pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop3.jpg');
  border: 0px;
/*   border-bottom: 1px solid 167491; */
}

.menu-block:hover {
 background-image: url('https://pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop3-hover.jpg');
}

.menu-block {
 width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/*   padding: 10px 0;  */
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-block-3 {
  min-width: 33%;
  flex-basis: 33.5%;
  max-width: 34%;
}

 .menu-block-divider {
  width: 1px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background-image: url(//pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop-li.gif);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menuTop">
  <div class="menu-block">
    <div class="icon-1"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-1">О сервисе</div>

  </div>
  <div class="menu-block-divider"></div>
  <div class="menu-block">
    <div class="icon-2"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-2" onclick="myFunction()">
      Услуги и цены </div>

  </div>

  <div class="menu-block-divider"></div>
  <div class="menu-block menu-block-3">
    <div class="icon-3"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-33">Контактная информация </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-1">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-1" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Техническое обслуживание авто</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Техническое обслуживание авто</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Акции</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-2" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-2" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Рулевое управление</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Рулевое управление - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена рулевой рейки</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт гидроусилителя руля (ГУР)</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
        <input class="hide" id="hd-3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="hd-3" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Трансмиссия</label>
        <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Трансмиссия- прайс-лист</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена сцепления</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Стоимость и ремонт вариатора</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагноситка и ремонт РКПП</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт раздаточной кородки TOD</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-2">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-4" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-4" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Двигатель</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Двигатель - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт турбин</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена маслосъемных колпачков</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена головок</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена колец</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена двигателя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена масла в двигателе</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена свечей накала</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт компонентов ГРМ</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена цепи ГРМ</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-5" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-5" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Топливная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Топливная система - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт топливной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт инжекторной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт узлов системы впрыска</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена и диагностика форсунок</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена топливного фильтра</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-3">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-6" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-6" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Система электрики</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Электрика - прайс лист</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-7" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-7" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Системы охлаждения</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Охлаждение - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена радиатора охлаждения</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена термостата</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-8" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-8" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Тормозная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Тормозная система - прайс-лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Тормозная система</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-4">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-9" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-9" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Выхлопная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Выхлопная система - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт выхлопной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена гофры глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена резинок глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена средней части глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена приемной трубы глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена кольца глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена прокладки катализатора</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена заднего глушителя</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-5">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-10" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-10" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Подвеска</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Подвеска - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагностика и ремонт ходовой</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагностика подвески</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена амортизаторов</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена ступичного подшипника</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена шаровой опоры</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена стоек стабилизатора</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена рычагов подвески</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена сайлентблоков подвески</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<header class="header-flex">
  <div class="article-header">Замена и ремонт головок двигателя <span class="article-header-price">от 3000 руб.</span></div>
  <button class="sidebar-button">Запрос цены и сроков</button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1240px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown-menu-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;

}

.dropdown-menu-column-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block-header {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #595959;
    background-color: #dedede;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block-element a {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #167491;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu-container {
    display: none;
}

.hide:checked+label+div {
    display: flex;
}


@media (max-width: 444px) {

    .hide,
    .hide+label~div {
        display: none;
    }

    .hide:checked+label+div {
        display: block;
    }

    .hide+label:before {
        background-color: #2CB1D9;
        color: black;
        content: "\002B";
        display: block;
        float: right;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        height: 16px;
        line-height: 16px;
        margin: 3px 5px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 16px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .hide:checked+label:before {
        content: "\2212";
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
        gap: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu-column {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .dropdown-menu-column-block-header {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu-column-block {
        border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
    }

    .dropdown-menu-column-block-element a {
        padding-left: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

}

.header-flex {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1240px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #1c1c1c;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.article-header {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.article-header-price {
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar-button {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(//pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/feedBackButton.png);
    height: 40px;
    width: 187px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #863e39;
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar-button:hover {
    background-color: #1fa6ce;
    background-image: none;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    max-width: 1240px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('https://pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop3.jpg');
    border: 0px;
    /*   border-bottom: 1px solid 167491; */
}

.menu-block:hover {
    background-image: url('https://pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop3-hover.jpg');
}

.menu-block {
    width: 33%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /*   padding: 10px 0;  */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-block-3 {
    min-width: 33%;
    flex-basis: 33.5%;
    max-width: 34%;
}

.menu-block-divider {
    width: 1px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    background-image: url(//pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop-li.gif);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menuTop">
    <div class="menu-block">
        <div class="icon-1"><img src=""></div>
        <div class="menu-block-1">О сервисе</div>

    </div>
    <div class="menu-block-divider"></div>
    <div class="menu-block">
        <div class="icon-2"><img src=""></div>
        <div class="menu-block-2" onclick="myFunction()">
            Услуги и цены </div>

    </div>

    <div class="menu-block-divider"></div>
    <div class="menu-block menu-block-3">
        <div class="icon-3"><img src=""></div>
        <div class="menu-block-33">Контактная информация </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu-container" id="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-1">
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-1" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-1" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Техническое обслуживание авто</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Техническое обслуживание авто</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Акции</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-2" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-2" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Рулевое управление</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Рулевое управление - прайс лист</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена рулевой рейки</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт гидроусилителя руля (ГУР)</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                    <input class="hide" id="hd-3" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="hd-3" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Трансмиссия</label>
                    <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Трансмиссия- прайс-лист</a></div>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена сцепления</a></div>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Стоимость и ремонт вариатора</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагноситка и ремонт РКПП</a></div>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт раздаточной кородки TOD</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-2">
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-4" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-4" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Двигатель</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Двигатель - прайс лист</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт турбин</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена маслосъемных колпачков</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена головок</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена колец</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена двигателя</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена масла в двигателе</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена свечей накала</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт компонентов ГРМ</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена цепи ГРМ</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-5" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-5" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Топливная система</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Топливная система - прайс лист</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт топливной системы</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт инжекторной системы</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт узлов системы впрыска</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена и диагностика форсунок</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена топливного фильтра</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-3">
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-6" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-6" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Система электрики</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Электрика - прайс лист</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-7" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-7" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Системы охлаждения</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Охлаждение - прайс лист</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена радиатора охлаждения</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена термостата</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-8" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-8" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Тормозная система</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Тормозная система - прайс-лист</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Тормозная система</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-4">
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-9" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-9" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Выхлопная система</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Выхлопная система - прайс лист</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт выхлопной системы</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена глушителя</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена гофры глушителя</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена резинок глушителя</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена средней части глушителя</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена приемной трубы глушителя</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена кольца глушителя</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена прокладки катализатора</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена заднего глушителя</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-5">
            <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
                <input class="hide" id="hd-10" type="checkbox">
                <label for="hd-10" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Подвеска</label>
                <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Подвеска - прайс лист</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагностика и ремонт ходовой</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагностика подвески</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена амортизаторов</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена ступичного подшипника</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена шаровой опоры</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена стоек стабилизатора</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена рычагов подвески</a></div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена сайлентблоков подвески</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<header class="header-flex">
    <div class="article-header">Замена и ремонт головок двигателя <span class="article-header-price">от 3000 руб.</span>
    </div>
    <button class="sidebar-button">Запрос цены и сроков</button>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.
Unfortunately your version breaks flex, as your can see if you run code snippet, that you provided. 
Even PC-width of a dropdown is compromised and all flex menu has become unadaptive.

Answer (score 0):

I fix your code. I use position absolute to resolve this problem

also, z-index is important

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1240px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block-header {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #595959;
  background-color: #dedede;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.dropdown-menu-column-block-element a {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #167491;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.hide:checked+label+div {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 444px) {
  .hide,
  .hide+label~div {
    display: none;
  }
  .hide:checked+label+div {
    display: block;
  }
  .hide+label:before {
    background-color: #2CB1D9;
    color: black;
    content: "\002B";
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 3px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 16px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .hide:checked+label:before {
    content: "\2212";
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    gap: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-column {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-column-block-header {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-column-block {
    border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  }
  .dropdown-menu-column-block-element a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.header-flex {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1240px;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.article-header {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.article-header-price {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sidebar-button {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(//pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/feedBackButton.png);
  height: 40px;
  width: 187px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #863e39;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.sidebar-button:hover {
  background-color: #1fa6ce;
  background-image: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  max-width: 1240px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('https://pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop3.jpg');
  border: 0px;
  /*   border-bottom: 1px solid 167491; */
}

.menu-block:hover {
  background-image: url('https://pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop3-hover.jpg');
}

.menu-block {
  width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*   padding: 10px 0;  */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-block-3 {
  min-width: 33%;
  flex-basis: 33.5%;
  max-width: 34%;
}

.menu-block-divider {
  width: 1px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background-image: url(//pulam.ru/wp-content/themes/avtoservis/images/menuTop-li.gif);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" id="menuTop">
  <div class="menu-block">
    <div class="icon-1"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-1">О сервисе</div>

  </div>
  <div class="menu-block-divider"></div>
  <div class="menu-block">
    <div class="icon-2"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-2" onclick="myFunction()">
      Услуги и цены </div>

  </div>

  <div class="menu-block-divider"></div>
  <div class="menu-block menu-block-3">
    <div class="icon-3"><img src=""></div>
    <div class="menu-block-33">Контактная информация </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-1">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-1" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Техническое обслуживание авто</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Техническое обслуживание авто</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Акции</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-2" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-2" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Рулевое управление</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Рулевое управление - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена рулевой рейки</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт гидроусилителя руля (ГУР)</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
        <input class="hide" id="hd-3" type="checkbox">
        <label for="hd-3" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Трансмиссия</label>
        <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Трансмиссия- прайс-лист</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена сцепления</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Стоимость и ремонт вариатора</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагноситка и ремонт РКПП</a></div>
          <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт раздаточной кородки TOD</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-2">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-4" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-4" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Двигатель</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Двигатель - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт турбин</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена маслосъемных колпачков</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена головок</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена колец</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена двигателя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена масла в двигателе</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена свечей накала</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт компонентов ГРМ</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена цепи ГРМ</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-5" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-5" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Топливная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Топливная система - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт топливной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт инжекторной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт узлов системы впрыска</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена и диагностика форсунок</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена топливного фильтра</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-3">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-6" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-6" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Система электрики</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Электрика - прайс лист</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-7" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-7" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Системы охлаждения</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Охлаждение - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена радиатора охлаждения</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена термостата</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-8" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-8" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Тормозная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Тормозная система - прайс-лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Тормозная система</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-4">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-9" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-9" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Выхлопная система</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Выхлопная система - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт выхлопной системы</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Ремонт и замена глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена гофры глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена резинок глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена средней части глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена приемной трубы глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена кольца глушителя</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена прокладки катализатора</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена заднего глушителя</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-column column-5">
    <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block">
      <input class="hide" id="hd-10" type="checkbox">
      <label for="hd-10" class="dropdown-menu-column-block-header">Подвеска</label>
      <div class="drodown-menu-column-block-element-hider">
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Подвеска - прайс лист</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагностика и ремонт ходовой</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Диагностика подвески</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена амортизаторов</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена ступичного подшипника</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена шаровой опоры</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена стоек стабилизатора</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена рычагов подвески</a></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu-column-block-element"><a href="">Замена сайлентблоков подвески</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<header class="header-flex">
  <div class="article-header">Замена и ремонт головок двигателя <span class="article-header-price">от 3000 руб.</span></div>
  <button class="sidebar-button">Запрос цены и сроков</button>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.
Unfortunately your version breaks flex, as your can see if you run code snippet, that you provided. 
Even PC-width of a dropdown is compromised and all flex menu has become unadaptive.